# Trying to make rating prediction

Tags: python, prediction

I'm working on the following function :

```
def prediction_rate(model_name):
  print("welcome ! \nplease enter the first text ! : ")
  ID1 = input()
  print("please enter the second text ! : ")
  rev = input()
  comment1=encoding(ID1)
  comment2=encoding(rev)
  y=model_name.predict([commentaire1,commentaire2])
  c = np.argmax(y)
  Switcher={
    0:'Satisfaction Percentage : {:.1f}'.format(
   (y[0][c]/5)*100)+ ' %'}

print(Switcher.get(c))
```

in this code, comment1 and comment2 are the inputs to make the prediction using a multi-input CNN model.
Comment1 and comment2 are preprocessed by the following question :

```
def encoding(text):
  text = clean_str(text)
  text = preprocessing(text)
  vocabulary,vocabulary_inv = build_vocab(text)
  text = pad_sentences(text,100)
  x_users = np.array([vocabulary[word] for word in text])
  x_test = sequence.pad_sequences(x_users, maxlen=100)
  return x_test
```

After running `prediction_rate(model_name)` I get this error :

```
 File "<ipython-input-26-8859e8cf819b>", line 1, in <module>
 prediction_rate(model_name)

 File "<ipython-input-25-e74c3c5bf609>", line 6, in prediction_rate
comment1=encoding(ID1)

 File "<ipython-input-24-73d50eec77a1>", line 3, in encoding
text = preprocessing(text)

 File "C:\Users\Amin Chaari\Apothek\data_clean.py", line 159, in preprocessing
 words=stems, lemmas(words)

TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
```

The preprocessing function :

```
def preprocessing(words):
 words = remove_non_ascii(words)
 words = to_lowercase(words)
 words = remove_punctuation(words)

 words = remove_stopwords(words)
 words  =stem_words(words)
 words=lemmatize_verbs(words)
 words= stem_and_lemmatize(words)
 words=stems, lemmas(words)
 return words
```

then :

```
def stem_and_lemmatize(words):
 stems = stem_words(words)
 lemmas = lemmatize_verbs(words)
 return stems, lemmas

stems, lemmas = stem_and_lemmatize(words)
```

Comment: lemmas[words] instead of lemmas(words)

Comment: @ncica still the same error !

Comment: @Amine Can you add the full error stacktrace so we can see where the error originates? The current error is only partial or you didn't add the code that corresponds to the error.

Comment: @Ralf I updated it, you can check it out !

Comment: @Amine The stacktrace shows that the error originates inside this line `text = preprocessing(text)`. Can you show your function `preprocessing()` ?

Comment: @Ralf yes you can check it above !

Comment: @Amine what is the data type of `lemmas` (if you do `print(type(lemmas))`) inside the `preprocessing()` function?

Comment: @Ralf as much as I know, it would be a list of words in the bare format

Comment: @Amine in that case the line `words = stems, lemmas(words)` obiously will raise an error because `lemmas` is a list and it cannot be called like a function. You will need to change that line.